# Determining whether there is a linear mapping T

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether there is a linear map $T$ such that $T(1,3,2)= (5,2,2)$, $T(2,-1,3)=(11,-6,3)$ and $T(4,-9,5)=(23,-22,6)$.
Someone please help me. I understood the lesson pretty well but I can't seem to know how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should ask yourself is whether or not the vectors
\begin{align*}
v_1= &= (1,3,2) & v_2 &= (2,-1,3) & v_3 &= (4,-9,5)
\end{align*}
are linearly independent. To answer this question, put them into the columns of a matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2  & 4  \\
3 & -1 & -9 \\
2 & 3  & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and find the nullspace. Assuming you can do this, we find that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null A=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\-3\\1
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
This tells us that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is not linearly independent because
$$
2\cdot v_1+(-3)\cdot v_2+(1)\cdot v_3=\mathbf 0\tag{1}
$$
So, if such a linear transformation existed, we could apply it to (1) to get
$$
T(2\cdot v_1+(-3)\cdot v_2+(1)\cdot v_3)=T(\mathbf 0)=0\tag{2}
$$
But using the linearity of $T$ would also give
\begin{align*}
T(2\cdot v_1+(-3)\cdot v_2+(1)\cdot v_3)
&= 2T(v_1)-3T(v_2)+T(v_3) \\
&= 2(5,2,2)-3(11,-6,3)+(23,-22,6) \\
&= (0,0,1)
\end{align*}
which clearly contradicts (2).

Comment: Thanks man, I was thinking of doing it this way but for some reason i got the reduced row echolen form of $A$ wrong